# When should bool.boolValue be used?

Tags: programming-practices, coding-style, swift-language

Recently a co-worker has taken to checking boolean values in the following manner:

```
if boolVar.boolValue {
    ...
}
```

These variable are generally declared explicitly as boolean types either using:

```
var boolVar: Bool!
```

or

```
var boolVar = false
```

I am under the understanding that if a variable is declared as a boolean then it should be treated as such. Meaning it can only ever be `true` or `false`, so it should be treated as such and shouldn't need to dive in to the `boolValue` property which states it is exactly the same.

This is how Apple defines it:

```
extension Bool : BooleanType {
    /// Identical to `self`.
    public var boolValue: Bool { get }
    /// Construct an instance representing the same logical value as
    /// `value`.
    public init<T : BooleanType>(_ value: T)
}
```

It seems to me this is useful for creating your own types which conform to `BooleanType`. I also feel this `.boolValue` property may come in handy if unwrapping a boolean from a dictionary or a JSON response but it feels weird in this instance.

My question is, is there ever a case where we should be checking booleans in this manner?

Comment: All that, just for a boolean?

Comment: @RobertHarvey see that's my thing, booleans should just be `true` or `false` but thanks to Swift's ability to extend any type and certain co-workers obsession with minute details, this has become an issue.

Comment: So what does the extension add that a simple bool variable doesn't provide?  Does it provide a string representation of its value, i.e. "true" or "false"?  Something else?

Comment: The extension listed above simply echos the value of the bool. For an actual bool variable I don't see what functionality it provides. But maybe for things extending `BooleanType` it may be useful? I don't know. But what he's doing is just weird to me.

Comment: Yes, I suspect that there's some code missing in your definition from Apple.

Comment: `BooleanType` *was* a protocol to describe types which can be used in control statements like `if`. It has been removed in Swift 3.

Comment: I name bool withe prefix is  isSomething if ( isSomething)

Comment: @RobertHarvey The `BooleanType` protocol generalized the interface of a boolean value, while decoupling it from the concrete `Bool` implementation. For example, this was useful at the time for allowing `NSNumber` (An Objective C class from the Foundation library, which stores a boxed number, similar to Java's `Integer`, `Boolean`, etc classes) to be used as if they were native Swift `Bool`s. This was really handy when dealing with ObjC code, because you could just do something like `if someNSNumber {`

Answer (score 1):

Never, for several reasons:

1. `BooleanType` was removed in Swift 3.
2. The implementation of `.boolValue` for `Bool` just returns `self`. Why stop at just one `.boolValue`? Why not `boolVar.boolValue.boolValue.boolValue.boolValue.boolValue.boolValue`?